# How do I install VMWare Tools v8 for Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to install VMWare Tools for Workstation, v8. Where is the download available? Is the ISO available already and I just need to tell VMWare to install?

Comment: Is this what you want? [Installing VMWare Tools](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html)

Comment: I don't have that option on my VM menu. I have a disabled "VMWare Tools Unavailable" option however..I cannot find the ISO either. And its not clear if it is supposed to exist on the guest or the host machine. The furthest I got was http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-installation-configuration.pdf , which in sum, basically tells me what I already know, that ~you need to install VMWare Tools~. ReallY?? I suspect that since I don't have the "VM > Install (or Upgrade) VMware Tools" option, I need to download the ISO. I have also tried "https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads", impossible..

Comment: It exists on the host machine as an iso. You can mount that iso as a virtual CDROM in the guest and then install from it.  (which is more or less what the menu option does for you).